# I need to hide table rows depending on their content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I have a simple table of domains and subdomains.

[image: My Table]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Table</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>doamin_name</th>
            <th>subdoamin_name</th>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td>bing.com</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>google.com</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>google.com</td>
            <td>images.google.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>google.com</td>
            <td>mail.google.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>google.com</td>
            <td>maps.google.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>yahoo.com</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>yahoo.com</td>
            <td>stores.yahoo.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>yahoo.com</td>
            <td>tw.news.yahoo.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>yahoo.com</td>
            <td>view.yahoo.com</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to show/hide subdomains when I click on domain row.

I tried jQuery slideToggle

```jquery
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on("click", "tbody tr:eq(1)", function(){
        $("tbody tr:nth-child(1n+3)").slideToggle(1000);
    });
});
```

It works fine when I specify row numbers manually, but I need to find them automatically  for every domain/subdomains, because table will grow in size.

So I need to check `subdomain_name` textContent:

- If it's empty - this is a domain. Add `EventListener` to it, so on click it will show/hide it's subdomains.
- If it's not empty - check `domain_name` textContect and add to rows that need to be hidden.

Comment: Could you share the html code?

Comment: Done. I added it to post.

Comment: Do you have to keep this data in this format? If not, I suggest you to use accordion component with bootstrap or jquery ui.

Comment: Yes, I need to keep it the way it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add class for the `<td>` of domain name using following css selector, then loop through the rows and using `.closest()`.
The`firstIndex` is to determine the row without subdomain value

```js
$(document).ready(function(){  
$('tr>td:nth-child(1)').addClass('domainTd');

$(document).on("click", ".domainTd", function(){   
    var domainName= $(this).text();
    var firstIndex=true;
    $('tr>td:nth-child(1)').each(function(index){    
      if($(this).text()===domainName){
        if(firstIndex){
          firstIndex=false;              
        }else{
         $(this).closest('tr').slideToggle()
        }   
      }             
    })
  });    
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>My Table</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>doamin_name</th>
            <th>subdoamin_name</th>
        </thead>
        <tr>
            <td>bing.com</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>google.com</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>google.com</td>
            <td>images.google.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>google.com</td>
            <td>mail.google.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>google.com</td>
            <td>maps.google.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>yahoo.com</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>yahoo.com</td>
            <td>stores.yahoo.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>yahoo.com</td>
            <td>tw.news.yahoo.com</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>yahoo.com</td>
            <td>view.yahoo.com</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't add anything to HTML table itself. My only option is to use textContent.

Comment: Don't use my code. It's works only for first domain. I need to add events to every domain row 1, 2, 6 and I need to find this rows using textContent, not manually.

Comment: Code edited, now it hide all the subdomain. Does that fit your expectation?

Comment: Unfortunately, not. I will probably delete my jQuery code from post, it's adds confusion. Again: when I click on row 1 - nothing happened, because there is no subdomains. When I click on row 2  - row 3, 4 and 5 should hide. When I click on row 6 -  row 7, 8, 9 should hide.

Comment: " when I click on row 1 - nothing happened, because there is no subdomains. When I click on row 2 - row 3, 4 and 5 should hide. When I click on row 6 - row 7, 8, 9 should hide."
If you run above code snipet, doesn't the above code exactly do that?

Comment: I'm sorry, yes it does, but it's hides only subdomains column. I need all the subdomain rows to be hidden.

Comment: Yes, amazing. Thank you